# How to match a string for a given reg expression in prolog?

Tags: regex, prolog

I am trying to match an expression which is similar to regular expression in prolog for a given input string.

```
match_function([_$]?[a-z]|[a-z][a-z_]*[a-z],"+ab_c").
false
match_function([_$]?[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z_]*[A-Z],"+AB_C").
...
```

Any pointers how to approach this case ? . Like how can I split the first argument and check each element of string one by one using pattern match ? something like

```
match([_$],[X|Xs]):-
member(X,"_$").
     match_next(NEXT_ELMENT_IN_THE_STRING)...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a job you just want to get done, use an existing regular expression library. There is one for SWI-Prolog that you can install by running `pack_install(regex)`.

If you want to/have to implement this for some other reason, you should proceed by first parsing the regex into a representation that is easier to work with, then write your `match` predicate using that. DCGs should be useful for both parts.

For example, your regex of `[_$]?[a-z]|[a-z][a-z_]*[a-z]` could be turned into a term like

```
choice(sequence([option(one_of(['_', '$'])), range(a, z)]),
       sequence([range(a, z), any(one_of([range(a, z), '_']), range(a, z)]))
```

which you can then match against lists of characters with rules like

```
match(one_of(Chars)) -->
    [C],
    { member(C, Chars) }.
```

If you are a complete beginner, this will not be easy, but we are happy to help with concrete problems!